# Issue with numpy logical operations

Tags: python, list, numpy, integer, logic

I am creating a game. Within the game, I have a numpy array (square) that begins with 0s. Players fill the array by adding their assigned integer to a certain location. The game is won by the player that fills an entire row, column, diagonal, or anti diagonal(?) with their number. Currently this is my function that checks for game success.

I have two issues:
1. I want the function to check for ALL player success and return a tuple (i.e. (True,2) if player 2 has won) instead of one at a time. The way the game works, there will never be two players who have won, so that isn't an issue. I will have a list of all the players playing (i.e. [1,2,3,4] for 4 players) that I can pass to the function.
2. I don't want a "for" loop, because I want to do this for a lot of iterations.

I have been struggling with logical operators in numpy, but I don't want to change this to a list or anything else.

```
def check_success(gm,player): #gm is game array
            for i in range(len(gm)):
                if (not any(gm[i]-player)) or (not any(gm[:,i]-player)):
                    return True
            if (not any(np.diag(gm)-player)) or (not any(np.diag(np.fliplr(gm))-player)):
                return True
            return False
```

Note: I suspect issue #1 cannot be solved without a for loop. If that is the case, I prefer issue #2 solved. I can always run the function multiple times, because the number of players will certainly be much fewer than the size of gm.

Comment: In the description you mention off-diagonals but your code seems to only address the two main diagonals. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I used the term off-diagonal incorrectly. I think I meant the diagonal and anti-diagonal. The code is correct, not the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In that case my answer should be fine. Let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: optimized code and benchmarks:

Timings

```
>>> stress_test(4, 1000, 2, 0, 0)
OP  : 0.322599 ms
pp0 : 0.451822 ms
pp1 : 0.140838 ms
>>> 
>>> stress_test(10, 1000, 4)
OP  : 1.051070 ms
pp0 : 0.425230 ms
pp1 : 0.166876 ms
```

Code

```
import numpy as np

def f_OP(board, p):
    for cp in range(1, p+1):
        if check_success(board, cp):
            return True, cp
    else:
        return False, 0

def check_success(gm,player): #gm is game array
            for i in range(len(gm)):
                if (not any(gm[i]-player)) or (not any(gm[:,i]-player)):
                    return True
            if (not any(np.diag(gm)-player)) or (not any(np.diag(np.fliplr(gm))-player)):
                return True
            return False

def f_pp0(board, dummy=None):
    for b in (board, board.T, np.einsum('ii->i', board)[:, None],
              np.einsum('ii->i', board[::-1])[:, None]):
        L = np.diff(b, axis=0).any(axis=0) | (b[0] == 0)
        ind = L.argmin()
        if not L[ind]:
            return True, b[0, ind]
    return False, 0

def f_pp1(board, dummy=None):
    D = np.einsum('ii->i', board)
    DP = D != 0
    if DP[0] and (D[0] == D).all():
        return True, D[0]
    L = DP & (D == board).all(0)
    I = L.argmax()
    if L[I]:
        return True, D[I]
    L = DP & (D == board.T).all(0)
    I = L.argmax()
    if L[I]:
        return True, D[I]
    D = np.einsum('ii->i', board[::-1])
    if D[0] and (D[0] == D).all():
        return True, D[0]
    return False, 0

def stress_test(n, k, p, wr=0.1, fr=0.4):
    from timeit import timeit
    data = np.random.randint(1, p+1, (k, n, n))
    data *= np.random.random((k, n, n)) < fr
    w = np.where(np.random.random((k,)) < wr)[0][:, None]
    pw = np.random.randint(1, p+1, w.shape)
    wp = np.random.randint(-2, 2*n, w.shape)
    i = np.where(wp < n, np.arange(n), wp-n)
    j = np.where((wp >= n) | (wp < 0), np.arange(n), wp)
    j[wp.ravel()==-1, :] == np.arange(n)[::-1]
    data[w, i, j] = pw
    glb = dict(data=data, p=p)
    kwds = dict(number=10, globals=glb)
    ref = None
    for f, glb['f'] in globals().items():
        if f.startswith('f_'):
            print('{:<4s}: {:8.6f} ms'.format(f[2:], timeit("for d in data: f(d, p)", **kwds) * 1000 / k))
            if ref is None:
                ref = np.array([glb['f'](d, p) for d in data])
                print(np.count_nonzero(ref))
            else:
                assert (ref == np.array([glb['f'](d, p) for d in data])).all()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The reality is, I probably will not require this for many players (usually only 2). If that's the case, a quick test has my function running faster (iterating over 2 players). I could use your implementation for many different players, but more importantly I was looking for a way to check columns and rows all at once without explicit iteration.

Comment: For instance, if I could use any()/all() to break down the game board row/column wise and give a 1D array of bool values for each row/column, then I could combine all arrays (row wise, column wise, diagonal (element), anti-diagonal (element)) and put it all in an if statement. I don't mind looping over the number of players.

Comment: @JamesCarter Strange, I ran a quick test with 2 players and a couple of 10x10 random filled boards and mine runs 5 times faster than yours. Maybe it depends on parameters. Could you be so kind and indicate roughly what parameters you expect (dimensions, fill percentage, # players)?

Comment: Here is the test I ran: fill%:0 (to actually test the entire iteration because the function stops execution at return statement), 2 players, 4x4. Please try your test again. I would love something that works 5 times faster! Note: Most likely the game wouldn't be run in a bigger scale than that test. Which is why I am looking for efficiency in that range of parameters.

Comment: @JamesCarter Nevermind, I messed that up, I was thinking I was testing 100 boards of size 10x10 when I was testing 10 boards of 100x100. For the 4x4 yours is indeed faster. But I made an optimized version which is a bit more than twice as fast even at that small size. Please check out the update.